# JavaFX 8: Adapting ListView Cell's height to its ScrollBar

Tags: listview, javafx-8, scrollbar, listcellrenderer, clipped

I have a `ListView` (horizontal orientation) that uses a `ListCell` to show its items. These cells are `Canvas`. When enough items are placed into the list, a vertical and horizontal `ScrollBar` are activated. When this happens, part of the cell's contents are clipped (at the bottom) by the horizontal scrollbar.

How can we set (or adapt) the list view's height so that when the scrollbar appears no clipping will occur? Is their a way to detect when a scrollbar becomes visible? Can we determine the scrollbar's height and simply make the lists's height tall enough?

I have tried several approaches via change listeners in the list view and the list view cell. But these don't seem to work.

TIA

Comment: Is that you are asking for how to show only the horizontal scroll bar and not the vertical scroll bar? If you can provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that would me more helpful.

Comment: @SaiDandem I am asking how to get rid of vertical Scrollbar when the ListView cell height is not large enough.  In other words how much should I increase the height by.
As far as the code goes, I am using Scala so I don't think that would be too useful. Anyway I am adding a snippet of the code in case the solution I came up with is useful to anyone else. Might not be the best way to go about this.

Answer (score 0):

I have come up with the following solution: add an event listener - every-time an element is added, removed or replaced resize the ListView's height. When resizing check wether you have only a vertical and/or horizontal scroll-bar. If only a vertical scroll-bar exists use its height and insets to get the cell height. If a horizontal scroll-bar also exists add its height too (height of the thumb). Here are the relevant code snippet (in Scala):

```
  def extendHeight(thumbnails: ListView[String], vertical: Option[ScrollBar], horizontal: Option[ScrollBar]): Unit = {
    (vertical, horizontal) match {
      case (None, None) => ()
      case (None, Some(_)) => ()
      case (Some(v), None) =>
        resizeHeight(thumbnails, v, 0)
      case (Some(v), Some(h)) =>
        val extra = if (h.isVisible) h.getHeight else 0
        resizeHeight(thumbnails, v, extra)
    }
  }

  def resizeToFrame(thumbnails: ListView[String]): Unit = {
    val (vertical, horizontal) = PStoryBoardUX.getScrollBars(thumbnails)
    PStoryBoardUX.extendHeight(thumbnails, vertical, horizontal)
  }

thumbnails.getItems.addListener( new ListChangeListener[String] {
      override def onChanged(c: Change[_ <: String]): Unit = {
        javafx.application.Platform.runLater( () => {

          // At thus point in time the scrollbars have not been updated
          // So we don't know if they will be active or not. Force this
          thumbnails.layout()
          // Now resize to remove the visible scrollbars
          resizeToFrame(thumbnails)
        })
      }
    })
```